# How to attach handler to React Bootstrap select component?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, select, event-handling, react-bootstrap

I try to attach event handler to react bootstrap select component [bootstrap select component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-controls).

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 'initial'
    };
  }
  handleSelect(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({
      value: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div> selected value { this.state.value }</div>
        <FormControl
          componentClass="select"
          placeholder="select"
          onChange={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
        >
          <option value="test" eventKey="select">select</option>
          <option value="asdas" eventKey="other">...</option>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but in `handleSelect`instead of clicked option value I get some Proxy object.

[Here is CodePen showing the problem.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmpxPq?editors=1111)

What is the proper way of attaching handlers to FormControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First argument in the `onChange` event handler is event object. You can access the selected value by looking at event target - `evt.target.value`:

```
handleSelect(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.value);
  this.setState({
    value: evt.target.value
  });
}
```